# How to make a background image overlap

Tags: css

I have a very simple background image of a couple of lines on my webpage.  The code I'm currently using for it is:

```
{
  background-image:url('stripe.png');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Super simple.  But when I'm scrolling down in the page, I want things to underlap it, rather than overlap it.
Considering it's a small image (only 8px tall and 1px wide), it needs to go the entire edge of the page, and needs to meet the top edges to look right.  Because of this, I don't know how to do it as anything other than a background image.  Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Edit: If you know of a way to do this as being something other than a background, that'd be great!  It doesn't need to be a background, so long as the effect is there.

Edit again:  Thank you, here is a link to the page in question:  What's going on really is that I want a bar to appear between the frames (but a nice looking bar, not like the ones that are automatically made) And I can't figure out how to make one that will stay on top.

I've got the two frames, and most pages don't scroll, so it's not a problem.  So I have the bar as the background of the bottom frame, but when viewing scroll able pages, the effect falls apart.

Thanks everyone!  I was able to edit things by adding a div at the top and having it formatted like this

```
#stripe {
background-image:url('stripe.png');
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 8px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
 }
```

That way I still had my image as the border, and was able to make the div exactly the right size and everything.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is not possible using just background images

Comment: Do you know how to do it in some other way then?

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS (all of the relevant bits) please :)

Comment: i'm not sure I get what you mean. An example (image) would be nice to make it clear what your looking for.

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HJrhf/) so like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a background, so it is in the back. If you want something in the front, you need to have an element that is in front of the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 #header {
     background: gold;
     position: fixed;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
 }
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3Sb9/1/)

Comment: Alright!  Thank you!  I combined yours and Ruddy's solution and was able to get it right!